# Event trigger for filename modification

Tags: python, linux, windows, filesystems, inode

Say I am reading and processing a file_A.log with inode 123 and the file_A.log is rotated to file_A _1.log with , now the file_A will be having inode 125 , how to know if the filename is changed or not and to proceed with processing file_A_1.log and then procees to file_A.log.

To be precise i would like to know the filename change has happened to a given inode or that a new file is created in the directory using python for cross platform.

I can run a task to keep a watch on the directory but i am expecting to get an event notification happened instead of getting known by a timer task.

Comment: Your question is tagged both Linux and Windows, but such events are OS-specific so there is no one answer for all platforms. In Windows the classic cookbook page for this is http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/watch_directory_for_changes.html ... it's in Python 2 but doesn't need much fixing for Python 3.